# Caching in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, caching, jdbc

I want to use **caching with JDBC.** 
How can I achieve that? 
Are there any built-in mechanisms or do I have to use 3rd party solutions?
What is best practise for caching with JDBC.

Thank You, Jack

EDITED:
what about CachedRowSet?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html

Comment: there's no answer. Frankly, there's no question: you can cache connections, `PreparedStatement`s, query results, etc., etc. For each type of caching, you'll get a different approach.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to cache. See http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/jdbc_caching.shtml

Comment: @alf, can you cache connections? and what do you do with cached connections ? :-) I guess you meant you could pool connections :-)

Comment: @aishwarya I don't think ranting on terminology is going to get us anywhere :) Point is, there are levels and levels of caching, and focusing on JDBC means missing the point.

Comment: @alf, sorry, no offense intended really! apologies if it felt that way. btw, caching and pooling are 2 different things and I won't want Jack to confuse that he could cache a connection (I have seen people try that!!). I am sure you would understand and agree that caching a connection is one not possible, second meaningless. I agree the question needs to be clarified on what level of caching is being sought, I assumed it to be data - my bad!!

Comment: I was thinking qbout caching query results, I am sorry if my question wasn't precise.

Comment: @aishwarya not necessary data. For example, `PreparedStatement`s are "cached", not "pooled"—still, they are not only "data," as there's often a server state involved. So it's more of a terminology question.

Comment: @JackMszczynski profile first, cache when you know you do the same work way too many times. `ehcache` is a decent option indeed.

Answer (score 1):

try [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/jdbc). JDBC does not have caching by itself, but ehcache is pretty good. if you want a more robust cluster safe cache, try oracle coherence. I typically do not put a cache at first and run some performance tests, only if tests indicate a need for a cache is when I put one.

Answer (score 0):

There is few options now:

- [JDBC-Cache-Driver](https://github.com/qwazr/jdbc-cache-driver)
- [DbdaTestDriver](http://dbdatestdriver.sourceforge.net)