# JAVA/SQL - Best way to run this insert

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I currently have a small database updater that'll insert/update a users IP address every time they enter the server. Since this is ran on an interval which empties a cache every 2 seconds, i really want to find a good quick method to update the table.

Here is what i currently use (MySQL only sadly :( )

```
INSERT INTO `iban_ipcache` VALUES (
'" + PlayerName + "',
'" + UpdatedTime + "', //This is just System.getCurrentMills
'" + PlayerIP + "')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES (
ip='" + PlayerIP + "', 
time='" + System.currentTimeMills() + "';"
```

-- This was modifed so it can be read more easily, the query also uses ` instead of '--

The query works perfectly but.. Well i have to change the IP AND the time no matter what. So if the IP doesn't actually change, it'll still attempt to alter it. The time is used for both GUI reasons, and cross server updating reasons. So basically every time an old user logs in, the database will treat them like they just got a  new IP.

My question is, is there any way to possibly check if BOTH the key and IP are the same without having to use Select?

Comment: Use preparedStatements. don't use string concatenation with SQL queries.

Comment: I modified it so it would be more easy for people to read. But thanks for the tip anyways

Comment: Database constraint may be.

Comment: @BobbyBou I think you should go for cache. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376531/caching-in-jdbc) if this can help you. I believe in hibernate we can achieve this using second level cache, need to check this with jdbc.

Comment: @pise Yeah caches might be my only option atm.

Comment: MySQL will detect on its own when you set a column to the value already stored and only update the other columns (time in your case). What are you worrying about?